# How to remove a selected option from html select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-events

My actual question is quite bit complicated compared to its title. I am very new to Javascript and jQuery so please bear with me.

I would suggest that you run this code first before reading my question so you can understand what I'm trying to do.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.4min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" > 
var selectedAddFootballPlayerId = '';
var selectedAddFootballPlayerName = '';
var selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId = '';
var selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName = '';

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#listboxFootballPlayers option').click(function() {
  selectedAddFootballPlayerId = $(this).attr('value');
  selectedAddFootballPlayerName = $(this).text();
 });

 $('#selectedFootballPlayers option').click(function() {
  selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId = $(this).attr('value');
  selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName = $(this).text();
 });

 $('input#btnAddFootballPlayerToList').click(function() {
  if (selectedAddFootballPlayerId == '') {
   alert("Select a football player to be added from the list.");
  } else {
   var option = new Option(selectedAddFootballPlayerName , selectedAddFootballPlayerId);
   $(option).html(selectedAddFootballPlayerName); 
   $('#selectedFootballPlayers').append(option);
   selectedAddFootballPlayerId = '';
   selectedAddFootballPlayerName = '';
  }
 });

 $('input#btnRemoveFootballPlayerFromList').click(function() {
  if (selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId == '') {
   alert("Select a football player to be removed from the list.");
  } else {
   var option = new Option(selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName , selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId);
   $(option).html(selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName); 
   $('#listboxFootballPlayers').append(option);
   selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId = '';
   selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName = '';
  }
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <select id="listboxFootballPlayers" size="5" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px;">
    <option value="l1">Cristiano Ronaldo</option>
    <option value="l2">Ricardo Kaka</option>
    <option value="l3">Lionel Messi</option>
    <option value="l4">Gerd Muller</option>
    <option value="l5">Johan Crujjf</option>
    <option value="l6">Franz Beckenbauer</option>
    <option value="l7">David Beckham</option>
   </select>
  </td>
                    
  <td>
   <table>
    <tr><td><input type="button" id="btnAddFootballPlayerToList" value="->" /> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" id="btnRemoveFootballPlayerFromList" value="<-" /></td></tr>
   </table>
  </td>
                        
  <td>
   <select id="selectedFootballPlayers" size="5" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px;"></select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Before I start with the question please take note:

`#listboxFootballPlayers` - The listbox on the left 
`#selectedFootballPlayers` - The listbox on the right

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I remove the selected item / option from `#listboxFootballPlayers` after I clicked on `->` button.
2. Why is it that when I click on `<-` after I selected an item / option from `#selectedFootballPlayers` it gives me a message `Select a football player to be removed from the list.` It seems to me that it doesn't assign the value on the variable `selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId`.

Please ask me if there are something that are not clear with my question. Please help.

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7vspM/

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post working code in jsFiddle or link to a site, so that we don't have to do as much typing

Comment: Instead of trying to store the selected player in a variable each time an option is clicked, why don't you simply get the selected option from the select box when the -> (or <-) button is clicked? This would make it simpler, would allow multi-selection, selection through keyboard instead of mouse, etc.

Comment: @BrianHoover Ok I'll try jsfiddle. It will be my first time.

Comment: @BrianHoover Here is the jsfiddle. Hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/7vspM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#listboxFootballPlayers option').click(function() {
        selectedAddFootballPlayerId = $(this).attr('value');
        selectedAddFootballPlayerName = $(this).text();
    });
    $('#selectedFootballPlayers option').live('click',  // `live()` event for `option` bcoz, option in this select will  
                                                        // create after DOM ready
    function() {
        selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId = $(this).attr('value');
        selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName = $(this).text();
    });
    $('input#btnAddFootballPlayerToList').click(function() {
        if (selectedAddFootballPlayerId == '') {
            alert("Select a football player to be added from the list.");
        } else {
            var option = new Option(selectedAddFootballPlayerName, selectedAddFootballPlayerId);
            $(option).html(selectedAddFootballPlayerName);
            $('#selectedFootballPlayers').append(option);
            $('#listboxFootballPlayers option:selected').remove();  // remove selected option
            selectedAddFootballPlayerId = '';
            selectedAddFootballPlayerName = '';
        }
    });
    $('input#btnRemoveFootballPlayerFromList').click(function() {
        if (selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId == '') {
            alert("Select a football player to be removed from the list.");
        } else {
            var option = new Option(selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName, selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId);
            $(option).html(selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName);
            $('#selectedFootballPlayers option:selected').remove(); // remove selected option
            $('#listboxFootballPlayers').append(option);
            selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId = '';
            selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName = '';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 2):

The problem is that you assign the click functionality before you create the element to assign it to. When you create your option you should assign it instead, like this:

```
$(option).click(function() {
 selectedRemoveFootballPlayerId = $(this).attr('value');
 selectedRemoveFootballPlayerName = $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question one, it's somewhat easier to simply move the selected option element from one list to the other:

```
$('#listboxFootballPlayers option:selected').appendTo('#selectedFootballPlayers');
```

I've commented out the lines that don't appear to be needed in the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7vspM/2/).

As for your second question, I've rewritten the `if`/`else` statement:

```
$('input#btnRemoveFootballPlayerFromList').click(function() {
    if (!$('#selectedFootballPlayers option:selected')){
        alert("First select a player to remove.");
    }
    else {
        $('#selectedFootballPlayers option:selected').appendTo('#listboxFootballPlayers ');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7vspM/3/).

References:

- [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Comment: You're welcome, I've also addressed the second part now, in my edit.